# MonoTouch facebook binding sample fails to run with latest ios-sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.ios, facebook-c#-sdk, xamarin

When I try to build the sample of the monotouch-binding of the facebook API, I got the following error:

```
Building: sample (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)
Performing main compilation...
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs /noconfig "/out:/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.exe" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" "/r:/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/ATMHud/sample/MonoTouch.Dialog.dll" "/r:/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/binding/Facebook.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Json.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG"  /t:exe "/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/Main.cs" 
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)

/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/Main.cs(217,33): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected


Build complete -- 0 errors, 1 warning

Compiling to native code
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" -v --nomanifest --nosign -sim "/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -r "/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/ATMHud/sample/MonoTouch.Dialog.dll" -r "/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/binding/Facebook.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Json.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll" -debug -profiling -nolink -sdk "5.1" "/Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.exe"
MonoTouch version 5.2.13 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
Copied /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.exe to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/sample.exe
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/monotouch.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/mscorlib.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/mscorlib.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/Mono.Security.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Core.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Xml.dll
Copied /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/Facebook.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/Facebook.dll
Copied /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/ATMHud/sample/MonoTouch.Dialog.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/MonoTouch.Dialog.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Web.Services.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Json.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Json.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.ServiceModel.dll to /Users/kovacsd/devel/mozdulj/Libraries/monotouch-bindings/facebook/sample/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/sample.app/System.ServiceModel.dll
Generated /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/main.m
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -arch i386  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -c /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/main.m -o /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/main.x86.o -DDEBUG  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/main.x86.o -o /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/sample -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework GameKit -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreData -framework ExternalAccessory -weak_framework AssetsLibrary -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework CoreBluetooth -weak_framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework EventKit -weak_framework EventKitUI -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GLKit -weak_framework NewsstandKit -weak_framework Twitter -weak_framework iAd -weak_framework CoreImage -weak_framework CoreText -weak_framework ImageIO -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreVideo -weak_framework QuickLook -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u _catch_exception_raise -force_load /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/libFacebookSDK.a
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=5.1   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/main.x86.o -o /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/sample -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework GameKit -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreData -framework ExternalAccessory -weak_framework AssetsLibrary -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework CoreBluetooth -weak_framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework EventKit -weak_framework EventKitUI -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GLKit -weak_framework NewsstandKit -weak_framework Twitter -weak_framework iAd -weak_framework CoreImage -weak_framework CoreText -weak_framework ImageIO -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreVideo -weak_framework QuickLook -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u _catch_exception_raise -force_load /var/folders/1p/0r0j38dn71jdt871gtxg6srm0000gn/T/tmp5dfe35b3.tmp/libFacebookSDK.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      ___23-[FBCacheIndex dealloc]_block_invoke_0 in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      _initializeStatement in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _dropTrimmingTable] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in libFacebookSDK.a(FBCacheIndex.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

mtouch exited with code 1

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 1 warning
```

I've tried to add Mono.Date.Sqlite but to outcome is the same.

After I reverted to an older revision it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's likely because the new version of the **native** library for Facebook requires **sqlite** while the previous version did not.

Adding `Mono.Date.Sqlite` will only help managed code, i.e. it will do dynamic linking, at **runtime**, if the code from that assembly is used. To *fix* the native code requirement the `sqlite` needs to be available at (native) **compile/link** time.

The *best* way to do this is to update the facebook bindings to make sure it's `[LinkWith]` attribute include the instructions to link with **sqlite** (more details in this [article](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types/Binding_Types_Reference_Guide?highlight=linkwith#LinkWithAttribute)).

You should also be able to add this inside your own project (but do not forget to do this for both `Debug|Release` and both `iPhone|iPhoneSimulator` configurations) by adding:

```
-gcc_flags "-lsqlite"
```

to the "Additional mtouch arguments" in your project's build options (more details in this [article](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linking_native_libraries)).

Comment: thanks for the details, I couldn't try this out yet but this sounds like the perfect answer

Comment: Could you clarify what to add to the Frameworks parameter of LinkWith?

I did get the second approach to work, but had to use:

-gcc_flags "-lsqlite3.0"

Comment: I never said you should add a *Framework*! What you want is to supply the same flags (as the `gcc_flags`). You can do this by using the `LinkerFlags` property inside the `[LinkWith]` attribute, which is documented in the link I provided.